# JavaFx Application in NB 6.7.1 in Ubuntu 11.04 OS

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu, javafx

I am working in Ubuntu 11.04 Platform, i want to use JavaFx in my NB 6.7.1 and i have installed plugin for that, but in my first application when i run the application, i got the Error as,

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined, cannot find "java" command.
```

at Run Time and Build Failed for this reason.

Can any one tell me the right answer ??

Comment: I got the answer as I set Configuration of Project to Browser....

Answer (score 0):

BTW, JavaFX script has been discontinued so I would recommend not spending much time familiarizing with it.

Instead, try JavaFX 2.0. JavaFX 2.0 is built as a standard java library = no new language to learn. Unfortunately, current betas are not supported on anything else than Windows - they may run on Mac but no way for Linux :(